# Why isn't padding-top applying to my section?

Tags: html, css, padding

I've got a section that should have 150px padding on the top and bottom of said section, but no matter what, I can't the padding to appear. An example is here: http://new.cajunland.com/recipe/double-seasoned-cajun-hamburgers/

Here's the code for the section:

```css
.wp-block-mkl-section-block .section-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: none;
    z-index: 0;
}
section.section-hero .wp-block-columns.has-2-columns {
    max-width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wp-block-columns {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.wp-block-columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
*, ::before, ::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.wp-block-column.col-two-third {
    flex-basis: calc(60% - 16px);
}
.wp-block-column {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.wp-block-column {
    flex-basis: calc(50% - 16px);
    flex-grow: 0;
}
.wp-block-column {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.wp-block-column.col-one-third {
    background: rgb(255,255,255,.9);
    flex-basis: calc(40% - 16px);
    padding: 16px 24px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wp-block-mkl-section-block section-hero" style="padding-bottom:150px;padding-top:150px">
        <div class="section-bg bg__stretched" style="background: url(http://new.cajunland.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/recipe-double-seasoned-cajun-burger.jpg) no-repeat fixed center/100%">
<div class="wp-block-columns has-2-columns">
            <div class="wp-block-column col-two-third">
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="wp-block-column col-one-third">
                <h1>Double Seasoned Cajun Hamburgers</h1>
                <p style="color:#000;"><strong>Yield:</strong> 4<br><strong>Prep Time:</strong> 15 minutes<br><strong>Cook Time:</strong> 10-15 minutes</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The padding is not getting applied, because the child element inside it have `position: absolute`. Absolute positioning is taken completely out of the normal flow of the page layout

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your padding *is* applying (add a 1px red border to the section and run a demo, then remove the padding-top and padding-bottom and run the demo again to see. Also, I'd recommend against mixing inline styles with your external CSS. It's unnecessary complexity and adds to the difficulty in keeping precedence straight (and makes it harder for others to help).

Answer (score 1):

I had checked your example page padding-top, and the padding-bottom is working. see below
[image: screenshort]

But you had fixed the section-bg section by using **position: absolute** so padding top and bottom is working but not effecting any things.
you have to give the padding to section-bg class.

```
.wp-block-mkl-section-block .section-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: none;
  z-index: 0;;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
  padding-top: 150px;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/arshiyakhanam_786/pen/GRRBmKX)

Comment: No, that didn't work at all. Instead the white, transparent box floated underneath the header.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is there but the .section-bg box has `position: absolute` and `top: 0`.

You could increase the top value and move the background property to the section. And maybe use `height: 300px` instead of the paddings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and remove the padding: 150px from top and bottom from inline styles.

```
.wp-block-mkl-section-block .section-bg {
    position: absolute;                 /* Remove this line */
    padding-bottom: 150px!important;    /* Add !important   */
    padding-top: 150px;                 /* Add !important   */
    top: 0;                             /* Remove this line */
    left: 0;                            /* Remove this line */
    bottom: 0;                          /* Remove this line */
    right: 0;                           /* Remove this line */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    max-width: none;
    z-index: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Jaakko was partially correct about switching position:absolute to relative in the .section-bg div. I also moved the background image to the parent section so it's now in  instead. Fixed it all. Thanks, everyone.